# Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret value for staging label: AWSCURRENT

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

After we create a secret and secret version using terraform once we try to fetch the data from that secret the error "Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret value for staging label: AWSCURRENT"  pop's for us, but once we try to verify the secret using AWS cli the label AWSCURRENT is present there.

Here the terraform Code:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secrets" {
  name                = "secrets"
  recovery_window_in_days = 0
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secrets-version" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(var.secrets)
  version_stages = ["AWSCURRENT"]
}
```

Here the output from AWS CLI over that secret

```
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:1111111111111:secret:secrets-bRFXt2",
    "Name": "secrets",
    "LastChangedDate": "2022-09-30T15:22:28.070000-03:00",
    "LastAccessedDate": "2022-10-02T21:00:00-03:00",
    "Tags": [],
    "VersionIdsToStages": {
        "aa6fd140-0648-4e5c-a69d-33dd5d7bcc6e": [
            "AWSCURRENT"
        ]
    },
    "CreatedDate": "2022-09-30T15:22:28.026000-03:00"
}
```

I understand that the secret have the correct label attached as showed before, but once we try to work with it, that's the error that Pop's.

`Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret value for staging label: AWSCURRENT`

Any idea what could be wrong here?